# Imprimir los numeros de la serie 1234 2345 3456 4567 ... hasta 13141516 en python con ciclo for

Tags: python

He intentado resolver este problema y tuve algunos inconvenientes porque no me está saliendo el ultimo resultado igual al de la respuesta que sería `1213141516`.

Hice un ciclo for con incremento en 1111 hasta ese valor y no me da el resultado. Si alguien podría ayudarme. Adjunto imagen.

Este seria mi procedimiento

```
for k in range(1234,13141516,1111):
    print(k)
```

Esta sería la serie

[image: Esta seria la serie]

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perdon, pero es mucho mas facil que esto, con 2 línas de codigo lo tienes:

```
for i in range(1, 13):
    print(str(i) + str(i+1) + str(i+2) + str(i+3))
```

Más corto aún (por [Candid Moe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/180118/candid-moe)):

```
for i in range(1, 13):
    print(f"{i}{i+1}{i+2}{i+3}")
```

Comment: Buena alternativa, creo que es mejor que pongas `sep=""` para mostrar los dígitos juntos.

Comment: Lo único es que en las primeras 2 soluciones que propongo puedes utilizar cualquier número, por ejemplo si usas `12345` funcionará sin hacer cambios, pero en este caso tendrías que modificar el código.

Comment: Hola, no necesita sep="", ni necesita que funcione con 5 digitos. El enunciado es simple de entender: Pintar una serie de numeros por pantalla. Lo puedes hacer de 1.000 maneras o (por ejemplo) buscar la más facil.

Comment: Candid, buena, la pongo en la respuesta. Todo lo que sea optimizar sin perder legibilidad -> I LIKE IT! Flambeado de mou para celebrarlo?

Answer (score 1):

No te confundas. No se está sumando 1 a cada dígito.

En realidad son 4 números y en cada iteración se le suma 1 a cada uno. Así:

```
arr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

for i in range(13):
    print(arr[0] + i, arr[1] + i, arr[2] + i, arr[3] + i, sep="")
```

O si lo prefieres con un ciclo más:

```
for i in range(13):
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[j] + i, end="")
    print()
```

Sin arreglo podría ser así:

```
for i in range(13):
    for j in range(1, 5):
        print(j + i, end="")
    print()
```

---

Con `sep` cambias el caracter que se escribe entre los parámetros imprimidos. Por defecto es un espacio.

Con `end` cambias el caracter que se escribe al final de la impresión. Por defecto es un salto de línea.

Comment: No tengo permitido usar listas, como podría hacerlo sin ello?

Comment: @Ezel y qué se supone que puedes usar?

Comment: Solo puedo utilizar ciclos for y while, el problema venia de resolver factoriales, y como no encontré algun patrón o formula me quedé sin ideas.

Comment: @EzelB7, Puedes utillizar generadores?

Comment: No, funciones ademas de for y while no se pueden usar.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Se me ocurre convertir primero el número `1234` a un `string`, porque el número, al ser un entero, no es iterable pero si lo convertimos a `string` es iterable, es decir, podemos acceder a cada uno de sus dígitos de la siguiente forma:

```
numeroString[0] sería 1
numeroString[1] sería 2
numeroString[2] sería 3
numeroString[3] sería 4
```

De esta forma se puede crear un ciclo e incrementar cada dígito para obtener el resultado deseado.

La **ventaja** de utilizar ese método es que si el número tiene más o menos dígitos no tienes que modificar el código.

Ejemplo:

```
numero = 1234

# Crear 13 iteraciones (Del 0 - 12)
for indice in range(13):
    # Inicializar el resultado como un string vacío en cada iteración
    resultado = ''
    # Recorrer cada dígito del número
    # Como numero es un entero no es iterable
    # pero si utilizamos un string podemos recorrerlo
    for digito in str(numero):
        # Adjuntamos (Concatenamos) los dígitos al resultado
        resultado += str(int(digito) + indice)
    # Imprimimos el resulatdo con los dígitos concatenados
    print(int(resultado))
```

Esto imprime:

```
1234
2345
3456
4567
5678
6789
78910
891011
9101112
10111213
11121314
12131415
13141516
```

Y otra solución utilizando `join` y una expresión generadora:

```
numero = 1234
for indice in range(13):
    print(''.join(str(int(digito) + indice) for digito in str(numero)))
```

Esto imprime:

```
1234
2345
3456
4567
5678
6789
78910
891011
9101112
10111213
11121314
12131415
13141516
```

### Edición

Se me ocurrió otra solución para no convertir el número a `string` realizando divisiones para obtener los dígitos pero la desventaja es que tienes que crear una variable para cada dígito por lo que si ahora tienes el número `12345` tendrías que crear otra variable y adaptar las divisiones.

```
numero = 1234

# Obtener los dígitos del número
digito1 = numero // 1000
remanente = numero % 1000
digito2 = remanente // 100
remanente = remanente % 100
digito3 = remanente // 10
remanente = remanente % 10
digito4 = remanente

for i in range(13):
    print(digito1 + i, digito2 + i, digito3 + i, digito4 + i, sep = '')
```

Esto imprime:

```
1234
2345
3456
4567
5678
6789
78910
891011
9101112
10111213
11121314
12131415
13141516
```

Answer (score 1):

Vistas la geniales respuestas de los maestros, solo me queda ir por el lado difícil, hacer la función reutilizable, respetando la consigna de **`No tengo permitido usar listas`**.

```
def nu( num, lim ):  
    cadena = str( num )
    largos = "1"
    for i in range( len( cadena ) -1 ):
        largos += "," + "1"
    print( cadena ) 
    while int( cadena ) <= lim:
        ca_ta = nuevoNumero( cadena, largos )
        cadena = ca_ta[ 0 ]
        largos = ca_ta[ 1 ]
        print( cadena )
        
def nuevoNumero( num, largos ): 
    res = ""
    pos = 0
    minNum = 0
    maxNum = 0
    while maxNum < len( num ):
        maxNum += int( largos[ pos : pos + 1 ] )
        letra = str( int( num[ minNum:maxNum ] ) + 1 )
        res += letra
        if( len( letra ) > int( largos[ pos : pos + 1 ] )):
            largos = largos[:pos] + str( len( letra )) + tam[pos + 1:]    
        pos += 2    
        minNum = maxNum
        
    return [ res, tam ]
    
num = 12345
lim = 1314151617
nu( num, lim )
```

La función **`nu`**, transforma el número recibido a `string`, y crea otra cadena con valor "1" (**largos**).
El `for` siguiente, completa **`largos`** agregandole en cada iteración, una coma y un "1", esta variable, nos indica la cantidad de posiciones que ocupa un número (ej: 5 ocupa una posición, 12 ocupa dos, al final quedaría algo así: "1,1,1,1").
Imprimimos el número recibido.
en el `while` llamamos a **`numeroNuevo`** que nos devuelve un array con los nuevos valores de **`cadena`** y **`largos`**, asignamos los valores a cada una e imprimimos **`cadena`**.

La función **`nuevoNumero`** es un poco más complicada.

```
int( largos[ pos : pos + 1 ] )
```

nos devuelve el largo de cada número, ya que **pos** va cambiando con cada iteración, ese valor se lo asignamos a **maxNum**.

```
letra = str( int( num[ minNum:maxNum ] ) + 1 )
```

acá extraemos una porción de **num** la convertimos en `int` le sumamos "1" y volvemos a convertirla en `string`, que agregamos a letra.
en el `if`, comprobamos si el largo de la letra generada es mayor que el contenido en **largos**, en cuyo caso nodificamos en valor guardado, concatenando la proción anterior de **largos** con el nuevo largo, y la proción posterior.
Solo nos resta aumentar en "2" **pos** y asignar a **nimNum** el valor de **maxNum**.
Fuera del `while`, devolvemos un array con **num** y **largos**.

Comment: Estaba pensando en alguna solución absurdamente larga y complicada. Vere si se me ocurre algo rebuscado.

Comment: @CandidMoe, maestro, no puedo negar que haya una solución más corta... a mi no se me ha ocurrido, dada la limitación puesta por el OP  **No tengo permitido usar listas**...